# Existing ListView must be replaced by Spinner

Tags: listview, spinner

I have been trying to find an answer for the following question. I am hoping stackoverflow can help me get an answer. Is there a way to replace an existing ListView with a Spinner?

I googled enough for 8 hours without a clear answer. Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is possible to do this by creating a fragment that will make use of the spinner UI in portrait mode while retaining the ListView on landscape mode.